# Concurrent indexing Postgres statement exit

Tags: postgresql

When creating an index concurrently in Postgres, how do you make the statement run in the background? Once I run the query in `psql`, the statement does not return and I'm not able to quit the process and disconnect SSH to server.

Edit: I understand we could use something like tmux to keep the shell alive in the background. But I'm trying to understand if Postgres' CONCURRENT index operation does not return immediately.

Comment: Do you know about tmux? It lets you disconnect while a command is still running.
https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki

Comment: I understand `tmux` can be used. But I just wanna know if this is the expected behavior with postgres. That concurrent indexing ops needs to have `psql` connected and does not work in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although the index is created concurrently, the DDL itself will not return immediately.

Ref: https://gist.github.com/bryanrite/36714b13e0aece2f6c43#safe

> Add an index concurrently (Example), Note: it will still take a long time to run the migration, but it won't write-lock the table.

Answer (score -1):

Use `screen` in linux,

```
screen -S session_name
```

then execute the command in psql.

You can detach from the screen session at any time by typing:

```
Ctrl+a d
```

To resume your session use

```
screen -r
```

Read [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/) for more info

This way you can let your process run in the background even though you disconnect your session.